# Fetch oracle data VARCHAR2(N BYTE) return blank string in JAVA

Tags: java, oracle, fetch, varchar2

I would like to know what's going on when, I'm trying to fetch data from ORACLE database. The datatype of the column is VARCHAR2(40 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE.

From @Thoma advise in comment section I've changed the pics into text.

In SQL DEVELOPPER, I have the following result

```
SELECT ZONE_DESC FROM IC_RATE_ZONES;
"ZONE_DESC"
VIRGIN ISLANDS UK
VIRGIN ISLANDS US
WALLIS AND FUTUNA IS
YEMEN
ZAMBIA
ZAMBIA MOBILE
```

And when I've tried to fetch those data in JAVA code:

```
try{
    con = conn.getOracle();
    stm = con.createStatement(); 
    Rs = stm.executeQuery("select ZONE_DESC FROM IC_RATE_ZONES");
    while(Rs.next()){
              System.out.println(Rs.getString("ZONE_DESC"));
    }
} catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get a blank result in my console output.

Comment: Instead of posting images you might want to post at least your code in properly formatted text form. This makes it easier to preserve (images can get deleted) and work with - and it shows some effort on your part.

Comment: @Thomas, sorry for this. this is a remote host and I cannot copy it because of the restriction. I'll try to write it all and post the text later.

Comment: What did you expect on the console? You add data to your model but you do not log the actual data to the console. Try `System.out.print(Rs.getString(1))`

Comment: @Vall0n have a look at the non-commented line right above where the data gets added to the model.

Comment: @Vall0n, I've added it twice time. In System.out.println(), just under "while" statement and in model.

Comment: Is there any chance that the code you execute isn't the code you see?

Comment: I'm sure that the code that the result I see is the part of the code that I wrotte. This is an UI and what you see is the console part

Comment: Can zone desc be `null`. The result count shown `50`

Comment: the column is "ZONE_DESC" VARCHAR2(40 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE

Comment: Have you tried Rs.getString("ZONE_DESC"); ?

Comment: @secret super star, Would you mean alter the column ?

Comment: Ah, sorry overlooked it...

Comment: @ChadNC, yes, i've already tried it, same result.

Comment: Can you try to use `Rs.getString("zone_desc");`.. but I highly doubt if it can give different result though.

Comment: i'll try it in lowercase and give you feedback

Comment: @secretsuperstar, same result

Comment: I don't see any issue with the code. The only possibility is data issue. Is there a possibility that you are connected to different database in Java and SQL developer.

Comment: Well, not sure if it helps..https://bjurr.com/jdbc-problem-resultset-getstring-returns-nothing/

Comment: well i've trying the ASCII and it gives somthing like that : ` 
oracle.jdbc.driver.DBConversion$AsciiStream@7c726c4e
oracle.jdbc.driver.DBConversion$AsciiStream@69a85c08
oracle.jdbc.driver.DBConversion$AsciiStream@241e894a`

Comment: Your column is declared with 40 Byte rather than 40 Char and this might be the issue due to encoding. Perhaps it is only the println that fails I am not sure, I think you should run this in the debugger to examine what exactly is in your result set.

Comment: @joakimdanielson, give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

THANKS A LOT FOR EVERYONE THAT take the time to answer it. the solution has been mentionned by @secretsuperstar in the comment section but i've do it wrong the first time.

https://bjurr.com/jdbc-problem-resultset-getstring-returns-nothing/

It have to get the ASCII first and read it. The datatype made it complicated.

here is the final result :

```
try{
        con = conn.getOracle();
        stm = con.createStatement();
         Rs = stm.executeQuery("select ZONE_DESC FROM IC_RATE_ZONES");

        while(Rs.next()){
            String str = new String();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(Rs.getAsciiStream("ZONE_DESC"));
            while(in.ready()){
                str = str + (char)in.read();
            }
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

thank you all. HOPE IT HELP SOMEONE ELSE